# How to send several keys in WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

How to make Python code in WebDriver to press Command+Shift+H buttons on keyboard (or keys)?

Update:

```
info: Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()"
debug: Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [INSTSERVER] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [INSTSERVER] Socket data received (8192 bytes)
info: [INSTSERVER] Socket data received (4494 bytes)
info: [INSTSERVER] Socket data being routed for 'cmd' event
info: [INSTSERVER] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"{\"UIAApplication\":{\"@\":{\"name\":\"AppName\",\"label\":\"AppName\",\"value\":null,\"dom\":null,\"enabled\":true,\"valid\":true,\"visible\":true,\"hint\":null,\"path\":\"/0\",\"x\":0,\"y\":20,\"width\":320,\"height\":548},\">\":[{\"UIAWindow\":{\"@\":{\"name\":null,\"label\":
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`send_keys()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, 'H')
```

Also see: [The Keys implementation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys).

Comment: I am trying to press "Home" button in iOS Simulator. It says     `wd.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, 'H')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`

Comment: @KirillZhukov you should first find an element to execute a `send_keys()`. `send_keys()` is a method of a WebDriver element.

Comment: @KirillZhukov `wd` is a `WebDriver` instance, not element.

Comment: So, how can I get the first element, aka main window?

Comment: @KirillZhukov could you give me the url so I can test?