# Selenium - send keys - what element should I use

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to scroll at the bottom of the page. I was adviced, here on SO, to do this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
element = driver.find_element_by_ ...
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL , Keys.END)
```

I can't figure out what element shoul I use. I was trying to put a webdriver instance instead of element but it did not work. I need something like current window element?

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This should be enough to make scroll to page bottom

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("site_name")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.END)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple javascript should be sufficient as well. Python syntax

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
body.click()
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
```

Looking at your previous question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936102) 
This works on mac. Change the combo for Windows.