# How Do I press shift + enter key using python selenium chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, selenium-webdriver

I have created bulk whatsapp message sender application into that I want to send multiline text message. but in whatsapp web when I tried to press enter it sends the message directly I want it to press shift + enter after some content in message to send multiline message.

Comment: `Keys.SHIFT`, `Keys.RETURN` ?

Comment: This would help you: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838269/how-can-i-get-selenium-to-get-a-keyboard-press-of-shift-enter-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send several keys in WebDriver with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206174/how-to-send-several-keys-in-webdriver-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206174/how-to-send-several-keys-in-webdriver-with-python).

If you want to press multiple keys at the same time, you can do:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element("Your Element").send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

For python

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211459/12346562)